# Bash output two results next to each other

Tags: grep, text-formatting, output, xml

I have an out from xmllint and egrep that I would like to print two fields next to each other.
e.g.

```
(xmlinput) xmllint --format | egrep reference\|sourcefile
<reference>ItemX</reference>
<sourcefile>://filepath/blah/blah/</sourcefile>
<reference>ItemY</reference>
<sourcefile>://filepath/blah/blah/</sourcefile>
.
.
<reference>ItemW</reference>
<sourcefile>://filepath/blah/blah/</sourcefile>
```

Is there a way to output the reference and the sourcefile elements next to each other?
e.g.

```
(xmlinput) xmllint --format | egrep reference\|sourcefile 
<reference>ItemX</reference><sourcefile>://filepath/blah/blah/</sourcefile>
<reference>ItemY</reference><sourcefile>://filepath/blah/blah/</sourcefile>
.
.
<reference>ItemW</reference><sourcefile>://filepath/blah/blah/</sourcefile>
```

Comment: You have to remove newline between `</reference>` and `<sourcefile>`. It can be easily done with e.g. sed

Comment: Are the `reference` and `sourcefile` nodes siblings beneath the same parent node in the XML document?

Comment: @Kusalananda No. They are elements in different nodes.

Comment: @mrc02_kr think I got fairly close piping out to sed 'N;s/\n//'     Thanks.

Comment: Are you able to share a bit more of the document so that someone may come up with a query for something like `xmlstarlet` that does this?  It would be good to see what paths (in the XML sense) that the two nodes have in relation to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[your command] | paste -d '' - -
```

will join consecutive lines.

Comment: Thanks! that is simpler and works the same as "sed 'N;s/\n//". They both produce a strange gap though. Nothing to bothersome though....

Comment: "strange gap"? Do you have trailing whitespace in the file? Check with `cat -e file`

Answer (score 0):

Once you start using `grep` on XML you're making assumptions about the input, and you will (almost certainly) no longer have valid XML output, so sometimes this isn't the best way forward.

That said, the path of least resistance often involves `grep`, so depending on your XML (a [well-formed minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be useful), you should be able to use `xmllint` with `--xpath` (`xmllint` >= 2.7.7 for `--xpath` support) like this:

```
xmllint --xpath "//reference|//sourcefile"  input.xml |
  pcregrep -o "(<reference>.*?</sourcefile>)"
```

where `xmllint` extracts elements using an [*XPath*](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_xpath.asp) expression that matches either (`|` as logical "or") of the elements you are interested in (`//` to select all matching elements anywhere in the input). The (non-XML aware) `pcregrep` (instead of `egrep`) matches each pair of elements with grouping, and outputs each matched group one per-line. 
One point to note here is the regex `.*?` which is a PCRE *non-greedy match* so it matches the *minimum* amount of text between the indicated tags rather than the whole line in one go (`xmllint --xpath ...` will dump everything onto one line).

It's "cheating" a little to use grep, we're making assumptions about the input, but `xmllint` is doing most of the heavy lifting. This approach can cause future parsing problems since [XML isn't "regular"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) and regular expressions aren't the best tool for the job.

The neat way to do this is with [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/docs.php):

```
xml select -t -m '//*' \
  --if 'local-name()="reference"' -c . \
  --elif 'local-name()="sourcefile"' -c . -o $'\n' input.xml
```

This searches all elements (`//*`), on matching `<reference>` that node is copied to output (`-c .`), else on matching `<sourcefile>` that node is copied to output with an extra newline output (`-o $'\n'`).

Answer (score 0):

Just pipe the data to `perl -pe 'chop if /^<reference>/'`